# Elasticsearch standard tokenizer behaviour and word boundaries

Tags: elasticsearch, token, tokenize, analyzer, word-boundary

I am not sure why the standard tokenizer (used by the default standard analyzer) behaves like this in this scenario:
 - If I use the word `system.exe` it generates the token `system.exe`. I understand `.` is not a word breaker.
 - If I use the word `system32.exe` it generates the tokens `system` and `exe`. I don´t understand this, why it breaks the word when it finds a `number` + a  `.` ?
 - If I use the word `system32tm.exe` it generates the token `system32tm.exe`. As in the first example, it works as expected, not breaking the word into different tokens.
I have read http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries but I still don´t understand why a `number` + dot (`.`) is a word boundary

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the question, the `standard` tokenizer provides grammar based tokenization based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm, as specified in [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/)
The rule http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries is to **not** break if you have `letter + dot + letter`, see [WB6](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB6) in the above spec. So `tm.exe` is preserved and `system32.exe` is split.
The spec says that it always splits, except for the listed exceptions. Exceptions [WB6](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB6) and [WB7](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB7) say that it never splits on letter, then punctuation, then letter. Rules [WB11](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB11) and [WB12](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#WB12) say that it never splits on number, then punctuation, then number. However there is no such rule for number then punctuation then letter, so the default rule applies and `system32.exe` gets splitted.