# Separators in standard analyzer of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that elasicsearch's standard analyzer uses standard tokenizer to generate tokens.
In this elasticsearch [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html), they say it does grammar-based tokenization, but the separators used by **standard tokenizer** are not clear.

My use case is as follows

1. In my elasticsearch index I have some fields which use the default analyzer standard analyzer
2. In those fields I want `#` character searchable and `.` as one more separator.
   **Can I achieve my use case with a standard analyzer?**

I checked what and all tokens it will generate for string **hey john.s #100 is a test name**.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "hey john.s #100 is a test name",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

It generated the following tokens

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hey",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "john.s",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "100",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "is",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "a",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "name",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

So I got a doubt that **Only whitespace is used as  a separator in standard tokenizer?**

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Does anyone know what are the separators in the standard tokenizer?

Comment: what is the version of elasticsearch?

Comment: elasticsearch version 8

Answer (score 2):

**Lets first see why it is not breaking token on `.` for some of the words:**

Standard analyzer use standard tokenizer only but standard tokenizer provides grammar based tokenization based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm. You can read more about [algorithm here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101540/elasticsearch-standard-tokenizer-behaviour-and-word-boundaries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135688/dots-in-field-arent-used-to-break-up-word-for-analyzer). it is not using whitespace tokenizer.

**Lets see now, how you can token on `.` dot and not on `#`:**

You can use [Character Group tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html) and provide list of character on which you want to apply tokenization.

```json
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "type": "char_group",
    "tokenize_on_chars": [
      "whitespace",
      ".",
      "\n"
    ]
  },
  "text": "hey john.s #100 is a test name"
}
```

**Response:**

```json
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hey",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "john",
      "start_offset": 4,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "s",
      "start_offset": 9,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "#100",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "is",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "a",
      "start_offset": 19,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 25,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 6
    },
    {
      "token": "name",
      "start_offset": 26,
      "end_offset": 30,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want # also searchable, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @sudheesh Configured above custom tokenizer for your field and you will be able to search # as well. So you can search `#100` but not `100` for above example.

Comment: But I want # alone searchable, Can you pls tell me if is there any way to do this? Without using n-gram tokenizer

Comment: @sudheesh why you want to search `#` . i dont think there is any other way then n-gram because all tokenizer will remove # while tokenization. You can check for char_replace filter but i am not sure it will work or not.