# elasticsearch tokenizer to generate tokens for special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a use case where special characters also should be searchable. I have tried some tokenizers like char_group, standard, n-gram.
If I use an n-gram tokenizer I am able to make special characters searchable(since it generates a token for each character).
But n-gram generates too many tokens, so I am not interested in using an n-gram tokenizer.
For example, if the text is **hey john.s #100 is a test name**, then the tokenizer should create tokens for [hey, john, s, #, 100, is, a, test, name]

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74024206/separators-in-standard-analyzer-of-elasticsearch) question for a detailed explanation.

Thank you.....

Comment: I think my use case can be achieved through **pattern tokenizers**. But I am not able to create the correct pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your use-case the best option would be to use a `Whitespace` tokenizer with a combination of `Word Delimiter Graph filter`.

For more information check the official documentation of Elasticsearch about whitespace tokenizer and word delimiter graph filter here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-graph-tokenfilter.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you suggested. But it didn't create separate token for # alone

Comment: Check type_table_path option in the Word Delimiter Graph filter.
(Optional, string) Path to a file that contains custom type mappings for characters. This allows you to map non-alphanumeric characters as numeric or alphanumeric to avoid splitting on those characters.